# Creating a wordpress widget - how to only load scripts when widget is on page

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am building a wordpress widget that allows the user to build a simple form (so that they can build forms in the customizer). As with all contat forms, I have a couple of scripts that I am loading, however, I only want to load these scripts if the contact form widget is active on the page.

Here is the start of my widget code:

```
if( !class_exists( 'Layers_Form_Builder_Widget' ) ) {
class Layers_Form_Builder_Widget extends Layers_Widget {

    function Layers_Form_Builder_Widget(){

        /* Widget code in here */

    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, my widget is wrapped in the class `Layers_Form_Builder_Widget`, so to call my processing script in the head of my page I have used the following:

```
public function layers_form_builder_process_script() {
        if( class_exists( 'Layers_Form_Builder_Widget' ) ) {
            require_once( LAYERS_FORM_BUILDER__PLUGIN_DIR . 'assets/js/magic.php' );
        }
    }
    add_action( 'wp_head', array( $this, 'layers_form_builder_process_script' ) );
```

The above code adds is uses my Layers_Form_Builder_Widget class as an if statement to load the processing script. My hope with this was that if the widget is not on the page, then the script doesn't show in the head - however, this is not the case.

Any help with figuring out how I load this script only on the page when the widget is being used would be appreciated.

Comment: [Check Wordpress Wiki](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_active_widget) `is_active_widget( $callback, $widget_id, $id_base, $skip_inactive );` is what i used and worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Use this function for knowing your widget is active or not

```
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_active_widget
```